# divide and search for specific words

Tags: c#, text, full-text-search, division

i have a text i want to divide it into equal 4 part and search for specific words that repeat in those part and display them

any ideas 
am working with c# vs 2008 and .txt files

Comment: Could you post an example of the 'text' and what you want to see as the outcome?

Comment: ok 
a text like " welcome to stackoverflow this site helps developers to share ideas and assist each other. at stackoverflow you can discuss. "

in that text, if u divide it into 2, 
stackoverflow should be returned/ displayed

as am working with about 4 pages 4-6 is ok after stopword removal
thanks

Comment: " welcome to stackoverflow this site helps developers to share ideas and assist each other. at stackoverflow you can discuss. " divide with 2 should give "stackoverflow"? Why not also "to"? You are not being clear.

Answer (score 0):

well, 4 equal parts can be done by taking string.length /4 and then taking substrings.  you could then do a .find within each string.

alternately, you could take a look a regular expressions.

Comment: hey YAMSPOG,
am new to c# and not that good with text processing any bit of code can help his is what i want" have a text file and want to divide it into 4 sections and display the words that appear in the 4 sections in a text box

using C# VS 2008 "